# Create dynamic form and validate/post it in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

I have in AngularJS a login form with a username and password input field. Above there is a button to load the register form. Then an email field will be added to the form.

But when I submit the register form, only the username and password input fields will be posted and not the email field.

```
Send Data after Login: {"username":"test","password":"test"}
Send Data after Register: {"username":"test","password":"test"}
```

Do you know why?

I created a Plnkr to demonstrate the problem:
http://embed.plnkr.co/HBEfITT3SNSZv44hj2x3/preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your additional field is inside an element with

```
ng-if="register"
```

ng-if is a directive that creates its own scope. So, when something is entered into the field `<input ng-model="email" ...>`, an email attribute is created and populated **in the ng-if scope**, instead of being created in the controller scope.

Rule of thumb: always have a dot in your ng-model, and always initialize the form model in the controller:

```
$scope.formModel = {};

<input ng-model="formModel.email" ...>
```

This will also make things simpler, since to post the form, all you'll have to do is something like

```
$http.post(url, $scope.formModel).then(...);
```

Comment: Thank you very much. The object has solved the problem.